# How to change deployment target in Xcode 12.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I'm seeing the following warning messages in xcode whenever compiling my app.

> The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
> set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
> 9.0 to 14.3.99.

Google says it's somehow related to cocoapods but i'm not using them (just swift packages) & i also don't see pod file in xcode's list of project files..

Deployment target is already set to 14 -
[image]

Any ideas on how to get rid of these messages?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Search for `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` in the search bar: you'll see that the human readable version (non-raw) string is `iOS deployment target`. So this is **not** about setting the simulator's target, this is about setting the iOS one. But you think you've already set the correct value for `iOS deployment target`.

Perhaps you are looking at the wrong target? Or looking at the project instead of the target?: See the picture below, select the target under `TARGETS` not `PROJECT`. This is because the target configuration overrides the project one:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your answer. I've just checked the settings and it appears i have it set correctly, here's the screenshot - https://d.pr/i/aV3eST

Comment: That's a different version you're using now: `14.4` not `14.0` and I have the same issue. I believe that is happening because Xcode currently warns against using versions newer than `14.3.99`. I **think this warning will disappear** if you change your deployment target to `14.3`. It would be interesting to see what your results are. I guess this warning can only be removed when using `14.4` as deployment target once a new version of Xcode is released.

Comment: it didn't disappear after changing it to 14.3.. Still the same warning - "
Showing All Messages
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99."

Comment: Did you try building for a physical device and does it have a similar warning?

Comment: Perhaps it might be one of your dependencies targetting iOS 8.0 if possible?

Comment: exactly the same warnings when building for my physical device (running on the latest iOS of course).

Comment: may be it has something to do with FacebookSDK i downloaded via swift package manager? Here's another screenshot https://d.pr/i/LukSIZ

Comment: I found this related github issue: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1491 are you on the latest version?

Comment: seems to be the latest one - here's the screenshot again https://d.pr/i/YUBMjB. .. but i found the following lines (iOS v8.0) in Package.swift file inside of SDK folder: https://d.pr/i/EsnrPY .. so i have this feeling that this is not the latest version of SDK but don't understand why xCode doesn't update it properly..

Comment: It looks like you're on 7.1.1, can you try [9.1.1](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/releases)